# Framework: How can I link any stylesheet to about.html Page?

Tags: cordova, hybrid-mobile-app, html-framework-7

Could anyone please tell me how can I link different css sheets to different html pages in framework7?
In my case I am looking to link css sheet that should only apply to about.html (not index.html) at framework7.io/get-started/ ?

Please guide me the as the code for about page at the given url does not have a `<head></head>` tag.

Comment: I am not sure I totally understand your question, but Framework7 works with callbacks on pages. That means that if you include a stylesheet in the head of index.html you can use it's classes in any other page you want.

Comment: If a page doesn't have `<head>` and `</head>` tags, that doesn't mean it doesn't have a head. Those tags are optional!